# Execute function between two times jodatime

Tags: java, jodatime

I wanted to know how I could execute a function between two times, say 6am and 3pm? For testing purposes, I have the code below but I am sure there is much better way to do what I want.

`if(dt.getHourOfDay() > 12 && dt.getHourOfDay()+dt.getMinuteOfHour() < 13){
// execute function
}`

The code, just checks if the hour is 12 and if time the time is between 12 and 12:01.

Can you please tell me a better to implement what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, in your example you'd want this for simplicity:

```
if (dt.getHourOfDay() == 12 && dt.getMinuteOfHour() == 0) {

}
```

Or perhaps:

```
if (dt.getHourOfDay() == 12 && dt.getMinuteOfHour() >= 0 && dt.getMinuteOfHour() < 1) {

}
```

If you don't want to compare directly, you can create two instants corresponding to the times you wanted, and use the isBefore and isAfter methods of AbstractInstant, or isBeforeNow, isAfterNow.   Something like:

```
Instant todayMidnight = new DateMidnight().toInstant();
Instant earliest = todayMidnight.plus(Hours.hours(6).toStandardDuration());
Instant latest = todayMidnight.plus(Hours.hours(15).toStandardDuration());
if (latest.isAfterNow() && earliest.isBeforeNow()) {
  // Execute 
}
```

A little kludgy since you would have to construct the todayMidnight object repeatedly, but very clear on whaty ou're doing.

But what are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to run something in a "cron" like fashion?  Or restrict access to some code to certain times of day?  Depending, there might be a better way.

Comment: Basically, I want to a run the program between 6am and 3pm. The premise of the program is to find the weather between those times.

Comment: I'm afraid you second code does not work I receive the following message "The method plus(long) in the type Instant is not applicable for the arguments (Hours)"

Comment: ETA: toStandardDuration(), which I think should fix it.  (I'm not compiling it, either way).

Answer (score 0):

I would really look into a scheduling library, this kind of stuff can get complicated really fast with timezones, DST, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution. It is not shorter but more obvious to understand.

```
int secBetween = Seconds.secondsBetween(new LocalTime(12, 0), dt.toLocalTime()).getSeconds(); 
if ( secBetween > 0 && secBetween < 60) { ... }
```